# Sum over k≠i of x_i + x_k

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python I have a numpy array `X` of values `xi` and I would like to create an array `F`, where each entry is the sum over all other entries of `X`.

Then `F` looks like this:

```
F= np.array[(x2+x3+...+xn),(x1+x3+...+xn),...,(x1+x2+...+xn-1)]
```

Here is it using a for loops:

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
F=np.zeros_like(X)
for i,f in enumerate(F):
    f = sum(np.delete(i,F))
```

Is there a way to do some numpy magic without an explicit use of a for loop?

What if the equation becomes more complicated like

```
F= np.array[(x2+x3+...+xn)^2+x1,(x1+x3+...+xn)^2+x2,...,(x1+x2+...+xn-1)^2+xn]
```

With a for loop it would be

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
F=np.zeros_like(X)
for i,f in enumerate(F):
    f = sum(np.delete(i,F))**2+X[i]
```

Comment: hmh, change your point of view: the first contains the sum of `all but x1`, the second `all but x2` and so on. That might help :)

Comment: Title changed, thank you

Answer (score 6):

Simply, `x.sum() - x`:

```
>>> x
array([0, 3, 1, 8, 3, 5, 6, 3, 8, 1])
>>> x.sum()
38
>>> x.sum() - x
array([38, 35, 37, 30, 35, 33, 32, 35, 30, 37])
```

For the other equation, each component is equal to:

```
(sum(x) - x(i))^2 + x(i) == sum(x)^2 + x(i)^2 - 2 * x(i) * sum(x) + x(i)
```

so you may still write it in vectorized form, as in:

```
>>> acc = x.sum()
>>> acc**2 + x**2 - 2 * x * acc + x
```